# Check and Uncheck Checkbox when Table Row is Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now I have my script setup so that when each checkbox inside a table row is checked it performs the functions required (addClass and some others).

I would also like the checkboxs to check/uncheck and perform the same functions when the individual table row is clicked.

**Here is my code for the checkbox functions:**

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').bind('click',function(e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.is(':checked')) { 
               num += 1;
               $('#delete_btn').fadeIn('fast');
               $this.parents('tr').addClass('selected'); 
               select_arr.unshift(this.id);
        } else { 
               num -= 1;
               if(num  <= 0) { 
                $('#delete_btn').fadeOut('fast'); 
               }
           $this.parents('tr').removeClass('selected'); 
               select_arr.shift(this.id);
        }
    });
```

What would be the best way to achieve the same result that this code does by just clicking the table row itself rather than the checkbox, but still allowing the checkboxes to function the same.

**Here is the table:**
[image]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Instead of binding to only the checkboxes, bind it to `<tr>` elements too. Then `$(this)` doesn't refer to the checkbox though, so it needs some extra coding.

Comment: is that table a plugin? Looks nice..

Comment: @Nick, Thanks! It's a simple customizable ajax table plugin that's built for php/SQL. Want me to throw you a link when complete? Should be soon - feedback is always appreciated.

Comment: Yes, please do send a link, i'm interested in seeing how this turns out.

Comment: @Nick: work in progress - https://github.com/j3ffz/Ajax-Data-Table/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("tr").click(function(){
    $(this).child("input:checkbox").eq(0).click();
});
```

You may want to add a class to the tr tags so that they are discernable from other tr tags on page (ex: <tr class="ticketTR">.. and just add the click function to those:::

```
$("tr.ticketTR").click(function(){
    $(this).child("input:checkbox").eq(0).click();
});
```

Comment: You could also try delegate(), which will work better with a dynamic table.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a great resource for this exact problem.

Check it out:

[Quick Tip: Click Table Row to Trigger a Checkbox Click](http://www.learningjquery.com/2008/12/quick-tip-click-table-row-to-trigger-a-checkbox-click)